# How to save to localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am looping through an array of objects, I want a user to be able to select and save the selected object properties to local storage. How do I achieve this

```js
const userData= [{ 
    name: 'Daniel',
    phone: "1234567",
    sex: "male"
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    phone: "1234367",
    sex: "female"
}];
    
return (
    <>
        <h3>Select an Account</h3> 
        <ul className="accountList">
            {userData && userData.map((item, id) => (
                <li key={id} >
                    <h3>{name}</h3>
                    <h3>{phone}</h3>   
                    <h3>{sex}</h3>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </>
);
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20localstorage

Comment: It seems you are using ReactJs, I recommend you to use useState hook rather than localstorage, you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're implementing the selection mechanism, but once you have the object you're looking to save, you can persist it to `localStorage` like so:

```
localStorage.setItem("User Account",JSON.stringify(<userAccountObject>));
```

And then later read it like this:

```
localStorage.getItem("User Account");
```

Comment: how do I implement the select mechanism

Comment: depends on how you want your interface to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const UserData = () => {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);

  const userData = [
    {
      name: "Daniel",
      phone: "1234567",
      sex: "male",
    },
    {
      name: "Jane",
      phone: "1234367",
      sex: "female",
    },
  ];

  const getUserAccount = () => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user_details");
    const parsed = JSON.parse(user) || selectedUser;
    if (!parsed) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <>
        <h3>Selected User</h3>
        <h6>Name: {parsed.name}</h6>
        <h6>Phone: {parsed.phone}</h6>
        <h6>Sex: {parsed.sex}</h6>
      </>
    );
  };

  const setUserAccount = (data) => {
    setSelectedUser(data);
    localStorage.setItem("user_details", JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Select an Account</h3>
      <ul className="accountList">
        {userData &&
          userData.map((item, id) => (
            <li
              key={id}
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => setUserAccount(item)}
            >
              {item.name} {item.phone} {item.sex}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
      <hr />
      {getUserAccount()}
    </>
  );
}

export default UserData;
```